# Which wire connect on my new dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

My home wiring is copper/white/green but the new dishwasher is black/white/green. I thought copper meant ground so I'm a little confused by the green being ground and what should connect to what.

[image]

Comment: Your general location might matter.  North America orange/copper can be used as a hot/black wire colour, but unusual.  Would be found more with conduit than wire cable system.  Ground can be only green colour(yellow stripes allowed) or bare(no insulation/copper)

Comment: The insulation is ORANGE. The wire inside it is copper. "Copper" as a wire color implies bare uninsulated wire (or wire that should not be in your house walls, like cheap clear speaker cables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in the US, your "copper"  is really orange and designates a hot wire. Connect it to the black on the DW.
( be sure the power is off)

White to white

Green to Green

Done.